# Método update no actualiza registros

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Estoy haciendo un sistema de peliculas y series pero tengo problemas con la actualización de los form.
AdminController (actualizado):

```
public function edit_serie_post(Request $request, $id) {
  $serie = new Serie;

  $v = \Validator::make($request->all(), [
    'serie_image' => 'required|mimes:jpeg,png',
    'serie_title' => 'required',
    'serie_description' => 'required',
    'serie_year' => 'required',
    'serie_trailer' => 'required',
    'serie_genre' => 'required',
    'serie_stars' => 'required',
    'serie_status' => 'required',
    'serie_featured' => 'required'
  ]);

  if ($v->fails()) {

    return redirect()->back()->withInput()->withErrors($v->errors());
  } else {

    $cover = $request->file('serie_image');
    $namec = $cover->getClientOriginalName();
    $cover->move(public_path('_assets/img/covers/'), $namec);

    $serie = Serie::findOrFail($id);
    $serie->serie_image = $namec;
    $serie->serie_title = $request->serie_title;
    $serie->serie_description = $request->serie_description;
    $serie->serie_year = $request->serie_year;
    $serie->serie_trailer = $request->serie_trailer;
    $serie->serie_genre = $request->serie_genre;
    $serie->serie_stars = $request->serie_stars;
    $serie->serie_status = $request->serie_status;
    $serie->serie_featured = $request->serie_featured;
    $serie->save();

    return redirect()->back()->with('message', 'Se actualizó correctamente.');
  }
}
```

Model Serie (actualizado):

```
class Serie extends Model {

  protected $table = 'series';

  protected $primaryKey = 's_id';

  protected $fillable = ['s_id', 'serie_image', 'serie_title', 'serie_description', 'serie_year', 'serie_trailer', 'serie_genre', 'serie_stars', 'serie_status', 'serie_featured', 'serie_slug'];
}
```

El problema es que tengo nombrado mi tabla diferente y sale que se actualizo, pero no se refleja nada. Quiero esa actualizarlo por el id de la serie.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El proceso de actualización no es correcto, ya que por un lado creas una instancia de la entidad Serie pero luego de asignar valor a todas las propiedades usas el método update.

- Si tú ruta ya recibe el id entonces debes usar este para filtrar tus modelos y encontrar aquel que quieres actualizar
- Del mismo modo el método update será sustituido por el método save

Quedando así:

```
 $serie = Serie::findOrFail($id);
  ..........
  ..........
 $serie->save();
```

Por cierto parece que tú llave primaria no sigue en su nombre las convenciones<sup>1</sup> de Eloquent dado lo cual debes declarar el nombre de está dentro de tu modelo así:

```
class Serie extends Model
{
    protected $primaryKey = 's_id';
}
```

**Fuente de consulta**

- [Métodos de actualización](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent#updates)
- [<sup>1</sup>Convenciones de Eloquent](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent#eloquent-model-conventions)

Comment: Gracias. Acabo de probarlo y no genera error y me sale el mensaje que se actualizó, pero no se actualiza nada realmente.

Comment: @julianpeñarete revisa lo último que agregue en la edición

Comment: Ya esta actualizado y nada. No se a que se deba ese error ahora.

Comment: No borres lo que ya tiene ti pregunta pero si edita y agrega como quedó el código con mi propuesta

Comment: Listo, ya lo actualice.

Comment: Aún tienes esto $serie = new Serie; quitalo de tu código puede generar problemas

Comment: ¡JA, JA, JA, JA, JA! Que pendejo. Gracias.